# How can I add a x-axis scrollable slider?

Tags: html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to add a x-axis scrollable slider, but cant seems to figure it out.

Here, I'm trying to do a  horizontal card scroll. If I add padding to the card Wrapper it extends itself out of the body. which I don't want to happen. Therefore I removed the padding and added `overflow-x: scroll` . I thought it will solve the issue and I will be able to scroll left/right.
Please tell me how to add the scroll without going out of the body.

Thanks in advance.

```css
.services {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: visible;
  height: fit-content;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.cardWrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.cardContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.cardContainer .cardsImage {
  width: 60%;
}

.cardContainer .cardsImage img {
  width: 100%;
}

.cardContainer .cardContents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <h1>Our Services</h1>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="cardContainer">
      <div class="cardsImage">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Qa Services">
      </div>
      <div class="cardContents">
        <h2>Qa Services</h2>
        <p>Our Qa engineers don't just test,they make your software application successful ensuring quality delivery with expert manual and automated testing services.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardContainer">
      <div class="cardsImage">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Qa Services">
      </div>
      <div class="cardContents">
        <h2>Qa Services</h2>
        <p>Our Qa engineers don't just test,they make your software application successful ensuring quality delivery with expert manual and automated testing services.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardContainer">
      <div class="cardsImage">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Qa Services">
      </div>
      <div class="cardContents">
        <h2>Qa Services</h2>
        <p>Our Qa engineers don't just test,they make your software application successful ensuring quality delivery with expert manual and automated testing services.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a simple wrapper that acts as a boundary for your scrollbar. Then inside you need the wrapper for your flex contents.
In addition, simple using a `width` on elements within a flex context is not enough. You need to provide [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) as well

```css
.services {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.cardWrapperOuter {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.cardWrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

.cardContainer {
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.cardContainer .cardsImage {
  width: 60%;
}

.cardContainer .cardsImage img {
  width: 100%;
}

.cardContainer .cardContents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <h1>Our Services</h1>

  <div class="cardWrapperOuter">
    <div class="cardWrapper">
      <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="cardsImage">
          <img src="./assets/images/QaServices.svg" alt="Qa Services">
        </div>
        <div class="cardContents">
          <h2>Qa Services</h2>
          <p>Our Qa engineers don't just test,they make your software application successful ensuring quality delivery with expert manual and automated testing services.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="cardsImage">
          <img src="./assets/images/QaServices.svg" alt="Qa Services">
        </div>
        <div class="cardContents">
          <h2>Qa Services</h2>
          <p>Our Qa engineers don't just test,they make your software application successful ensuring quality delivery with expert manual and automated testing services.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cardContainer">
        <div class="cardsImage">
          <img src="./assets/images/QaServices.svg" alt="Qa Services">
        </div>
        <div class="cardContents">
          <h2>Qa Services</h2>
          <p>Our Qa engineers don't just test,they make your software application successful ensuring quality delivery with expert manual and automated testing services.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```